# Disable vuetify v-data-table prev-icon permanently

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there a way to disable the `prev-icon` in the `v-data-table` footer section, the way it is done on the first page?
I tried setting the `footer-props` like:

```
footerProps: {
  'prev-icon': null,
},
```

This hides the icon, but the button remains clickable on pages > 1

Obviously i could use css to hide the button, but I would like to use vuetify to handle it instead.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have code to repro? you want to hide it all the time on all pages, or only when there is no prev data (like on the first page)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a native Vuetify way to handle this case. Using 'prev-icon': null will just not render the arrow icon for the previous button, but the button itself is still there and active (as you noticed).

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried `prev-icon:false`?